# How to use the python map function?

Tags: python

my code =

```
dir = 'C:\\Users\\fgdr1\\Desktop\\Code\\Python\\220923'
temp = os.listdir(dir)
logs = []
for i in temp:
    if 'data_log' in i:
        logs.append(i)
for i in temp:
    if str(len(logs)-2) in i:
        lastlog = i
```

I want to use the map function...
How do i can??

// sorry.I know my question was weird.
my intentions => I want to write this code using the map function instead of using the for statement.The purpose is to shorten the length of the code.

Comment: I think you want to use "filter" function instead of "map" function!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm what is your problem, please describe in detail your requirements.And first step you can use
 `logs = [i for i in temp if if 'data_log' in i]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).